# Additive and Multiplicative Error in $n!$ Approximation

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, factorial, approximation-theory

Let $S(n)=\sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\big)^n$ be the approximation of interest to $n!$.

What are good lower and upper bounds on the following two functions $$(1)\mbox{  }|S(n)-n!|?$$ $$(2)\mbox{  }\frac{S(n)}{n!}?$$

Comment: You can find these bounds by considering the "Stirling Series"

Comment: hmmm. could you please make it explicit?

Comment: $S(n)$ refers to which of Stirling approximations ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Presented $S(n)$ I am concerned.

Comment: As  mixedmath commeneted, there are many Stirling approximations (called the "Stirling Series"). Which one do you want to work with ?

Comment: I just want to know the difference between $S(n)=\sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\big)^n$ and $n!$ or their ratios. Thats it.